# VBA Looping to check conditions on two ranges

Tags: vba, excel, nested-loops

I have a problem with a simulator I'm doing for work.
I'm doing a simulation of the delivery service (I work for a fast food company).

I need a macro that checks several conditions through loops.

It first has to check if the order time is within a one second interval (this interval is also looped to increase 1 second and this is the outermost loop) AND if the order is "on hold" or has already been delivered.

Then it checks if the order and the agent that will deliver are coming from the same restaurant.
If that holds, then it has to check if the order time is greater than or equal to the time where the deliver agent is available.

If all that holds then it changes the order status to "Delivered", it also changes the time for the deliver agent as the time when he comes back to the restaurant. Finally it adds a counter for each delivery agent to see how many each agent delivered.

```
Sub loop1()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Timer starts
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String
StartTime = Timer

'Defines last row for both ranges
Sheets("Reloj").Select
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Embajadores").Select
Dim Lastrow2 As Long
Lastrow2 = ActiveSheet.Range("f" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range, pedido As Range
Set rng = (Worksheets("Reloj").Range("K12:K" & Lastrow))

Dim embajadores As Range, cell As Range
Set embajadores = (Worksheets("Embajadores").Range("f19:f" & Lastrow))



Sheets("Reloj").Select
'One second increment to this cell, which will begin at 13:00:00 for 
'little more than an hour.
For i = 1 To 3780
Cells(3, 3) = Cells(3, 3) + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
ActiveSheet.Calculate

'Start looping for each order 
        For Each pedido In rng
'Start looping for each delivery agent
            For Each cell In embajadores
            Sheets("Reloj").Select
'Check if the order time is between the two times (cells 3,3 is current time
'and cells 3,4 is one second more than 3,3)
            If pedido.Value >= Cells(3, 3) And pedido.Value < Cells(3, 4) And pedido.Offset(0, 1) = "Waiting" Then
'Checks if the order is coming in from the same restaurant 
                If pedido.Offset(0, 2) = cell.Offset(0, -1) Then
'Checks if the order time is greater than or equal than the delivery agent availability time
                        If pedido.Value >= cell.Value Then
                            'Changes the status to delivered
                                pedido.Offset(0, 1) = "Delivered"
                                Worksheets("Reloj").Calculate
                             'Changes the agent availability time to the delivery time of the specific order
                                cell.Value = pedido.Offset(0, 9)
                             'Adds one to the order counter
                                cell.Offset(0, 1) = cell.Offset(0, 1) + 1

                       End If
              End If
          End If
       Next cell
    Next pedido


Next i

'Finishes timer and shows MsgBox
    MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
MsgBox "The simulation ran in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes", vbInformation

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The problem I'm seeing right now is first that the loop is very slow, I believe this is because it's checking both the order and the delivery agent for every iteration. I believe this isn't necessary because it first should check if the order time is between the two clock times and also if the order is in status "Waiting". I understand this issue but have not been able to resolve it.

And second but most important, I can't exit the loop correctly. This means that the loop is working fine, it's going through all the conditions correctly. However, when it goes to check if the order time is greater than the availability time (after checking that it's the same restaurant) and none of the delivery agents apply to the condition, then it just skips it. 
I would like for it to insert the clock time in the delivery time like this:

```
Else
pedido.Value = Cells(3,3).Value + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
```

When I tried this it didn't work because it didn't loop through every row first, it just exited to the Else the first time the condition was not met.

Please help, I understand my syntax is very poor since I'm not a coder and also English isn't my first language.

Here is an example of my tables:

**rng**

```
the first column is my order time
second column is status
third column is restaurant
```

[image: Order table (called rng)]

**embajadores:**

```
first column restaurant, 
second column is availability time, 
third column is order counter
```

[image: Delivery agent table (called embajadores)]

Please help, I know I'm close to getting it but I can't get that last final part.

-----------------------Edit-------------------------------------------------------------------------

The issue I have right now is such and I will explain it with an example:
Let's imagine all of the delivery agents for restaurant 1 are out on the street and they all come back at 1:15pm. However, an order for that restaurant comes in at 1:13pm.

Right now, it's leaving that transaction skipped because none of them achieve the condition (I couldn't post an image of this)

As you can see, it skipped all 3 transactions of restaurant Zona 4 because it didn't find a delivery agent. What I want is I want these orders to be delayed (I thought about adding one second to the time until one delivery agent achieves the condition).

(Couldn't post an image of this)

All of these agents came in after the orders were placed and therefore they weren't assigned an order.

I KNOW right now I don't have an `Else`condition for this to happen but I don't know how to do this. Please help. Also, if I place the

```
Else
pedido.Value = Cells(3,3).Value + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
```

in the innermost If then it will get me out of the loop when it finds the first observation that doesn't fit the conditions even if there might be an available agent further down.

Comment: Some quick wins: Move `Sheets("Reloj").Select` outside the loop - it never changes. Do you have worksheet calculation turned off?  If not, remove all of the `.Calculate` lines. Use a `With` block for `pedido`.

Comment: @Comintern Hi. Thanks for the first tip. I do have worksheet calculation off that's why I'm using the `.Calculate`
As for the last tip, can you give me a tip on how to use the `With` block? And how would that help me?

Comment: Plenty of online info on using `With`. But you can start by wrapping your `If pedido` block in a `With pedido` block, replacng all references of `pedidio.` with `.` in that block

Comment: @dbmitch I have done as you said and the loop is working so thank you. However, I still need help with getting the final replacement of the order time with the clock time.

Comment: What does that mean? Can you describe what's happening now - what should happen and what part of the code is not working - do it in an EDIT at the bottom of your question - NOT in the comments

Comment: You can probably troubleshoot this yourself and find the problem/solution with adding debug statements before your if condition. Use `Debug.Print` for each of the variables and cells in your IF line - and place them just before your IF - then check the Immediate Window and see what values aren't what you expected

Comment: My preference for writing a simulation is to do it in pure VBA (instead of constantly writing values to and reading from the spreadsheet). It is needlessly slow to use the spreadsheet as a data structure. Get values from the worksheet at the beginning of the simulation and dump output to the worksheet when it is done. Not only would such an approach likely be faster, but it would be a cleaner design which allows you to focus on the logic of the simulation. Unfortunately, this would require your code to substantially rewritten.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks for the tip. However I'm a heavy Excel user and not a heavy coder which explains why I would choose this approach.